# MSBuild Copy fails with a strange error message

Tags: android, visual-studio, msbuild, marmalade

I'm stuck completely and need your help )))

MSVS cross-platform toolchain contains an msbuild script named **Android.Common.targets**, which has a target named **CopyAntPackageContentToOutput**, and the thing is that when this script executes (during *Marmalade SDK* native debug build) - Copy task fails to move a number of **.jar** files to an intermediate directory and prints:

```
Task Parameter:
1>                         SourceFiles=
1>                             c:\code\projects\develop+jf\marmalade\extensions\nsfirebase\sdk\libs\android\firebase-messaging-cpp\classes.jar
1>                                     CopyToOutputDirectory=Always
1>                                     Link=libs\classes.jar
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=c:\code\projects\develop+jf\marmalade\extensions\nsfirebase\sdk\libs\android\firebase-messaging-cpp\classes.jar
1>                                     TargetPath=libs\classes.jar
1>                             c:\code\projects\develop+jf\marmalade\extensions\androidsupport\sdk\support-core-ui\classes.jar
1>                                     CopyToOutputDirectory=Always
1>                                     Link=libs\classes.jar
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=c:\code\projects\develop+jf\marmalade\extensions\androidsupport\sdk\support-core-ui\classes.jar
1>                                     TargetPath=libs\classes.jar
```

(... and so on, had to cut the log a bit)

And then the error message:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(344,5): error MSB3094: "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 39 item(s). They must have the same number of items.
```

I get that msbuild probably fails because I have multiple **.jar** files with the same name **classes.jar**, but how do I fix that without renaming the files?

Answer (score 0):

> but how do I fix that without renaming the files?

It seems the problem is that `SourceFiles` contains multiple files but copy to the one destination.

Since you do not want to rename the source files, you can try to modify the copy target `CopyAntPackageContentToOutput` not to copy to the same folder by using a recursive copy:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles">  
    <Copy  
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"  
        DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'c:\MyDestinationTree\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"  
    />  
</Target>
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

See the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267030/why-doesnt-msbuild-copy-as-i-would-expect) for some more info.

Hope this helps.